# Sort an array inside an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

if I have a big collection of array, what is the fastest way to sort and return the first 5 items?

Array of Object:

```
[
  {
    "name" : "placeA",
    "menus" : [ 
        {
            "sold" : 5,
            "name" : "menuA"
        }, 
        {
            "sold" : 20,
            "_id" : "menuB"
        }, 
        {
            "sold" : 1000,
            "_id" : "menuC"
        }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name" : "placeB",
    "menus" : [ 
        {
            "sold" : 300,
            "name" : "menuD"
        }, 
        {
            "sold" : 400,
            "_id" : "menuE"
        }, 
        {
            "sold" : 50,
            "_id" : "menuF"
        }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name" : "placeC",
    "menus" : [ 
        {
            "sold" : 1500,
            "name" : "menuG"
        }, 
        {
            "sold" : 450,
            "_id" : "menuH"
        }, 
        {
            "sold" : 75,
            "_id" : "menuI"
        }
    ]
  }
]
```

Expected Output:

```
[
    {
      "sold" : 1500,
      "name" : "menuG"
    },
    {
      "sold" : 1000,
      "_id" : "menuC"
    },
    {
      "sold" : 450,
      "_id" : "menuH"
    },
    {
      "sold" : 400,
      "_id" : "menuE"
    },
    {
      "sold" : 300,
      "name" : "menuD"
    } 
]
```

The only possible way that I'm able to think of is to create an array that is filled all the menus and then sort the menus and then slice the first 5 items. I don't think this way is good enough for sorting a huge collection of array in real use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), and clean it up with [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to flatten the Arrays as you go, and [destructing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get straight to the 'menus' Array

```js
const data = [{name:"placeA",menus:[{sold:5,name:"menuA"},{sold:20,_id:"menuB"},{sold:1e3,_id:"menuC"}]},{name:"placeB",menus:[{sold:300,name:"menuD"},{sold:400,_id:"menuE"},{sold:50,_id:"menuF"}]},{name:"placeC",menus:[{sold:1500,name:"menuG"},{sold:450,_id:"menuH"},{sold:75,_id:"menuI"}]}];

let newArray = data
  .reduce((acc, {menus}) => [...acc, ...menus], [])
  .sort((a, b) => b.sold - a.sold);

console.log(newArray);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.map()`, `.reduce()`, `.concat()`, `.sort()`, and `.slice()`.

```js
var arr = [{
    "name": "placeA",
    "menus": [{
        "sold": 5,
        "name": "menuA"
      },
      {
        "sold": 20,
        "_id": "menuB"
      },
      {
        "sold": 1000,
        "_id": "menuC"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "placeB",
    "menus": [{
        "sold": 300,
        "name": "menuD"
      },
      {
        "sold": 400,
        "_id": "menuE"
      },
      {
        "sold": 50,
        "_id": "menuF"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "placeC",
    "menus": [{
        "sold": 1500,
        "name": "menuG"
      },
      {
        "sold": 450,
        "_id": "menuH"
      },
      {
        "sold": 75,
        "_id": "menuI"
      }
    ]
  }
]

var newarr = arr.map(v => v.menus).reduce((a, c) => a.concat(c));
console.log(newarr.sort((a,b) => b.sold - a.sold).slice(0,5));
```

I'm not sure if this is the fastest way, though.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Yousername said, you can also you [`flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) :

```
array
.map((a) => a.menus) // select menus
.flat() // all sub-array elements concatenated
.sort((a, b) => b.sold - a.sold) // sort by key sold
.slice(0,5) // select the first 5
```